Unable to Resolve Import in Java Project for open-match matchmaking
I'm developing a game using Java and Spring Boot, and I'm integrating Open Match for matchmaking. I'm encountering an issue with resolving the import for openmatch.MatchmakingGrpc in my Java project.
Steps I've Taken:
Cloned the Open Match Repository:
I cloned the Open Match repository from GitHub using:
git clone https://github.com/googleforgames/open-match.git --branch release-1.8.1
Built the Open Match Project:
I built the project using:
cd open-match
make build

Installed Artifacts to Local Maven Repository:
After locating the JAR files (e.g., openmatchfrontend-1.8.1.jar), I installed them using:
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-jar> -DgroupId=com.google.openmatch -DartifactId=openmatchfrontend -Dversion=1.8.1 -Dpackaging=jar
Configured Maven Dependencies:
In my Spring Boot project's pom.xml, I added:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.openmatch</groupId>
    <artifactId>openmatchfrontend</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>

Added Repository Configuration:
I added the repository configuration to my pom.xml:
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>open-match</id>
        <name>Open Match Repository</name>
        <url>https://github.com/googleforgames/open-match/tree/release-1.8.1</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

Issue:
Despite following these steps, I am still unable to resolve the import:
import openmatch.MatchmakingGrpc;
import openmatch.MatchmakingGrpc.MatchmakingBlockingStub;
import openmatch.MatchmakingOuterClass.MatchmakingRequest;
import openmatch.MatchmakingOuterClass.MatchmakingResponse;

The error message is:
The import openmatch.MatchmakingGrpc cannot be resolved
(Similarly, for other imports as well)
Environment:
Java Version: 11
Spring Boot Version: 2.5.6
Maven Version: 3.8.1
Additional Details:
I have run mvn clean install and mvn dependency:tree to ensure that dependencies are correctly resolved, but the issue persists.
The JAR files are successfully installed in the local Maven repository, and I can see them in the .m2 directory.
Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
